# print nested inner data in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to print the `total_price` data in this nested queryset.
tried:
`print(data['quotes_description']['total_price'])`
but it's throwing me `TypeError`: `list indices must be integers or slices, not str`.
If any help would be much appreciated. thank you so much in advance.

```
"data": [
        {
            "id": 35,
            "quotes_description": [
                {
                    "id": 51,
                    "total_price": 0,
                },
                {
                    "id": 52,
                    "total_price": 3000,
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
```

Comment: is this data JSON Response?

Comment: yes sir @Gnanavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the exact response.So, first you convert your JSON response using
`json.loads()`.

```
data = [
    {
        "id": 35,
        "quotes_description": [
            {
                "id": 51,
                "total_price": 0,
            },
            {
                "id": 52,
                "total_price": 3000,
            }
        ],
    }
]

for i in data:
    for j in i["quotes_description"]:
        print(j["total_price"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Both `data` and `data[0]['quotes_description']` are lists of dictionaries. You need to iterate over them to get each of the `total_price` values.

```
for element in data:
    for quote_description in element['quotes_description']:
        print(quote_description['total_price'])
```